# Copy all opened tabs texts by selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I wrote following script that copy all already opened tabs texts in Firefox:

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import time

def copy_text_from_tabs(num_tabs, output_file):
    # Delay to ensure you have time to focus on Firefox
    print("Please focus on Firefox within the next 5 seconds...")
    time.sleep(5)

    # Go to the first tab (Ctrl + 1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '1')

    # Delay to allow time for the page to load
    time.sleep(1)

    # List to store the text from each tab
    tab_texts = []

    # Loop through the number of tabs specified
    for tab_num in range(1, num_tabs + 1):
        # Select all text, copy, and verify
        copied = False
        while not copied:
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Give it a short moment for Ctrl + A
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
            time.sleep(0.5)  # Short delay to allow clipboard to update
            tab_text = pyperclip.paste()

            # Check if the text was successfully copied and is not empty
            if tab_text.strip():
                copied = True
            else:
                print(f"Retry copying from Tab {tab_num}...")
                time.sleep(1)  # Delay before retrying

        tab_texts.append(f"Tab {tab_num}:\n{tab_text}\n{'/' * 25}\n")  # Add separators between tab texts

        # Switch to the next tab (Ctrl + Tab)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab')
        time.sleep(1)  # Delay to allow time for the page to load

    # Join all the tab texts
    all_text = '\n'.join(tab_texts)

    # Save the text to the output file
    with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(all_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_tabs_to_copy = 100  # Change this number to the desired number of tabs
    output_file_name = "all_tabs_text.txt"

    copy_text_from_tabs(num_tabs_to_copy, output_file_name)

    print("Text copied from tabs and saved to 'all_tabs_text.txt'")
```

above script must go to first tab using `CTRL + 1` at first and then select all text in each tab using `CTRL + A` and then copy selected texts by `CTRL + C` and go to next tab using `CTRL + TAB`

Now my problem is sometimes my script bypass `CTRL + A` step and not select all texts and copy nothing using `CTRL + C` **(Note that this problem happen only sometimes)**
I even added some delay using `time.sleep` to `CTRL + A` step but the problem was not solved.

**How can I fix my script problem and what is my script problem?**